# How do I set the start_url of a manifest.json to be the root of the site?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have a `manifest.json` and it has a `start_url` property that I want to point to the first file of my single page application.

This is `index.html`, and it's the root of the site. I want this to be the `start_url`, but that file is never asked for as a URL.

How do I point `start_url` at the relative root of the site?

For instance, suppose the site is at `https://example.com`, what should the value of `start_url` be in `https://example.com/manifest.json`? I want the PWA to start at `https://example.com` and **not** `https://example.com/index.html`. The PWA might be put on a different domain, so `start_url` needs to be relative, not absolute.

Comment: You can use relative paths for `start_url`, so `"start_url" : "./index.html"` should work - or is that not what you meant? See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#start_url.

Comment: @TomDavies Then the user goes to `https://example.com/app` but the start URL becomes `https://example.com/app/index.html` or `https://example.com/index.html`.

Comment: It's not clear why Tom's response won't accomplish what you're asking for. Using `"./index.html"` or `"./"` (if you don't want to include the `index.html`, for some reason) should work.

Comment: @JeffPosnick So user is on `https://example.com/app` and adds an app based on `https://example.com/app/manifest.json` - when they click/tap on that it goes to `https://example.com/app/index.html`. That has the same content, but is a new path to the browser and not cached unless I do it manually - easy enough, but it feels clunky to add the extra duplicate route.

Comment: You can use `"./"` in that case. But I'd also recommend using a SW caching solution that knew that `./` and `./index.html` represent the same document, instead of treating each of them differently when fulfilling a navigation. For instance, `sw-precache` will generate a SW that responds to both of them using the same cached HTML document same by default: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#directoryindex-string

Comment: Have same problem....

Comment: I'm not sure it is real clear to others, but, using a relative url for either or both start_url and/or scope would place it in direct relationship to the url the manifest file is loaded from. The only way according to spec is to use absolute url's for scope and/or start_url. This opens an array of other situations such as the sw seeing the manifest and scope of the service worker. May even lead to a specific response header being returned, "service-worker-allowed" to allow it to happen.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you are running in the root of a site, for instance `https://example.com/manifest.json` or `https://test.example.com/manifest.json` you can use `"start_url": "/"`.

However, this will also map `https://example.com/test/manifest.json` to `https://example.com/`, which fails because it's in a folder outside the scope of the manifest.

Instead, if you are using a sub-directory you need to set both a `scope` and the `start_url`:

```
"start_url": "./"
"scope": "."
```

This will cause `https://example.com/test/manifest.json` to map to `https://example.com/test/` as expected.

Comment: In my case I use firebase dynamic links to shorten urls.  So `example.com/app/**`is the dynamic link.  When I set the start_url to "/" I get a 404 page.  Do you know how I should be handling this so that it also works with dynamic links?

Comment: @KyleAbens it depends where the link is dynamic - if you're using JS to rewrite URLs that won't work here, but server side you can, so long as the `start_url` path is relative to the location of the manifest.

Comment: Comment for `@angular/pwa` users. You also need to change `"index": "/index.html"` to `"index": "/"` in `ngsw-config.json`.

Answer (score 11):

Your start_url should be set to the following in your manifest file.

```
"start_url": "/"
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks

Comment: This won't work in a subfolder, so `https://example.com/test/` will try (and fail) to set the root as `https://example.com/`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changing your `start_url` to

```
"start_url": "/"
```

or for sub-directory (see [Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128412/8680805) for details)

```
"start_url": "./"
"scope": "."
```

For the people testing the `start_url` changes in the `manifest` on **Chrome Browser** in Android, the changes may not reflect right away for the users of your PWA. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks#update-webapk),

> Chrome will periodically compare the locally installed manifest
> against a copy of the manifest fetched from the network. If any of the
> properties in the manifest required to add the PWA to the home screen
> have changed in the network copy, Chrome will request an updated
> WebAPK, reflecting those new values.

This period is in 1 day intervals for new versions of Chrome (76 and up). This period is in 3 day intervals for Chrome 75 and earlier versions. This is what I've experienced and what I've done to force Chrome to fetch the new manifest (for testing & validation purposes) was to (1) uninstall the PWA, (2) clear Chrome data, and (3) reinstall the PWA

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand where the page is relative to the server. The local host or where you are accessing the website from starts for node.js servers.

For example if I want to run my website from manifest.json to be the root website, this is what I will write. In this basis, the root page of the file is index.html.

```
{
"start_url": "/index.html"
}
```

Remember to add a service-worker.js that connects to the index.html page too.

You can refer to the documenation for more information:

References:

1. Web App Manifest Recipe Book: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest
2. Introduction to Service-Worker.js https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-scripting-the-service-worker
3. Service-Worker.js tutorial. https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-scripting-the-service-worker

Comment: Caleb thanks, but this isn't what I'm asking - I'm directing external users to `example.com`, the server then serves up a default page (it's `index.html`, but it could be `default.asp` or anything else, it's up to the service). The user never sees `example.com/index.html` in the URL. Now, in `example.com/mainifest.json` I don't want to direct users to `example.com/index.html` (especially as users won't have it cached, breaking the PWA), I want to direct them to `example.com` - see the accepted answer for how to do that.

Comment: @Keith: 
Ok but it may be good to think about routing between pages after getting (400) requests from the start_html of the web manifest.json file as mentioned in @Eric V. answer of 

```json
    {
start_html = "/"
    }

<https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.9/docs/guide/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef.html>
<https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/pwa/tutorial-pwa-web-app-manifest.html>

Comment: Yes, you need whatever route that's in the `start_url` to return 200, if it returns a 400/bad request your PWA won't work. Eric V's answer didn't work because `"start_url": "/"` routes sub-directories to the domain root, as I explained in a comment on that answer. Yes, the path also needs to be in the service worker scope.

Answer (score 0):

In Create React App the `start_url` is set to `"."` which seems to do the job. But I didn’t find any documentation confirming this yet.

Answer (score -2):

I can even go from `DevTools > Application > Manifest > start_url` link to the page, switch to offline in network panel and reload the page and get the full page from the service worker.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Cheers for the response, but I don't think you've understood the question. In my `manifest.json` file, hosted in the root of my web application, what should `start_url` be set to when it is also the root of the web application. For instance the start page is `https://example.com`, what should the value of `start_url` be in `https://example.com/manifest.json`?